# Help with regex / ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, rubular

Hey guys, so I'm making a script to featch words/results off of this site (http://grecni.com/texttwist.php), So I already have the http request post ready, ect.

Only thing I need now is to fetch out the words, So I'm working with an html source that looks like so:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Text Twist Unscrambler</title>
<META NAME="keywords" CONTENT="Text,Twist,Text Twist,Unscramble,Free,Source,php">
</head>
<body>

<font face="arial,helvetica" size="3">
<p>
<b>3 letter words</b><br>sae &nbsp; sac &nbsp; ess &nbsp; aas &nbsp; ass &nbsp; sea &nbsp; ace &nbsp; sec &nbsp; <p>

<b>4 letter words</b><br>cess &nbsp; secs &nbsp; seas &nbsp; ceca &nbsp; sacs &nbsp; case &nbsp; asea &nbsp; casa &nbsp; aces &nbsp; caca &nbsp; <p>

<b>5 letter words</b><br>cacas &nbsp; casas &nbsp; caeca &nbsp; cases &nbsp; <p>
<b>6 letter words</b><br>access &nbsp; <br><br>
Found 23 words in 0.22962 seconds


<form action="texttwist.php" method="post">

enter scrambled letters and I'll return all word combinations<br>
<input type="text" name="l" value="asceacas" size="20" maxlength="20">

<input type="submit" name="button" value="unscramble">
<input type="button" name="clear" value="clear" onClick="this.form.l.value='';">
</form><p>

<a href=texttwist.phps>php source</a>
- it's kinda ugly, but it's fast<p>

<a href=/>back to my page</a>

</body>

</html>
```

I'm trying to fetch the words like "sae", "sav", "secs", "seas", "casas", ect.

Any help?

This is the farthest i've gotten, don't know what to do from here.: [link text](http://screens.rickmasta.com/3g.jpg)

Any suggestions? Help?

Comment: You need to take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want any kind of robustness you really want a parser, as mentioned by Adrian, [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org) is most popular solution.

If you insist, aware of the [madness](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) that you may be in for as the page becomes more complex the following may help:

Search for a line that matches

```
/^<b>\d+ letter words/
```

and then you can dig out the bits like so:

```
a = line.split(/<br>/)[1] # the second half
a.gsub!('<p>', '') # take out the trailing <p>
res = a.split(' &nbsp; ')# this is your data
```

That being said, this isn't anything you want in production code. You'll be surprised how learning a parser will change how you see this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use a HTML parser like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/).